# MySQL Eliminate duplicate values after group by

Tags: mysql

I have the following table `persons`:

| ID | Country | E-Mail | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | US | first | Tim |
| 2 | US | second | Elsa |
| 3 | UK | second | Elsa |

I want to group by country (having one record per country) and eliminate all duplicate emails in one query.

So the desired result would simply be:

| ID | Country | E-Mail | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | US | second | Elsa |

I tried the following query:

```sql
SELECT
    max(id),
    max(email),
    persons.country
FROM
    persons
GROUP BY
    persons.country;
```

But then I have the record `Elsa` twice which I don't want because the email is already existing. Adding the email to the group by is obviously also not correct.
Somehow I need the possibility to exclude the duplicates before or after the group by has been applied.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you prefer us/second/elsa over uk/second/else and why us/first/tim is not in the desired result.

Comment: When you say you want to 'group by country', what do you mean?  Should there be one row per country, with some kind of total against each country, or do you mean you want many rows per country but all rows with the same country shown together?

Comment: By "group by country" I mean there should be one record per country. Afterwards (or beforehand) I want to eliminate/exclude all duplicate emails.
@P.Salmon It doesn't matter if the first or second record is prioritized but in the end it should only be one because there are 2 of the same mail.

Comment: So if there are, for example, 15 records with 'US' for the country, and the desired result set has one row for 'US', what should be shown in the 'E-Mail' and 'Name' columns?

Comment: I still don't get it, you could eliminate the duplicate email second thus losing us/second/elsa and validly have 2 rows in your resultset aka us/first/tim and uk/second/elsa based on country..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of any stated logic lets assume that the duplicate you want to keep has the lowest id (which is another assumption) and furthermore you wish the highest id per country in the result (another assumption). So in stages

```
with cte as
(
select e_mail,min(id) minid
from t
group by e_mail),
cte1 as
(select country,max(id) maxid
from t 
where exists (select minid from cte where id = minid)
group by country
)
select t.*
from t 
join cte1 on  t.country = cte1.country and 
     cte1.maxid = t.id
```